# Merge several PDF together and create new PDF/A with Apache PdfBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm using the Apache PdfBox to preset several non PDF/A forms and use the `PDFMergerUtility` to merge these PDFs together and create a byte array of the new PDF.

```java
PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();

// presetting forms of these PDFs is omitted for readability
mergerUtility.addSource(new File("a.pdf"));
mergerUtility.addSource(new File("b.pdf"));
mergerUtility.addSource(new File("c.pdf"));

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mergerUtility.setDestinationStream(outputStream);

try {    
  mergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
  return outputStream.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  log.error("Unable to merge documents", ex);
  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to merge", ex);
}
```

Is there a way to tell the `PDFMergerUtility` to create a valid PDF/A document that cannot be modified anymore?

Comment: Are the source files PDF/A ?

Comment: No they are not

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with merge. Converting a PDF into PDF/A is a very complex topic, unless you created it yourself. I rather suggest you use a product from Callas or PDF-Tools or another company.

Comment: If you add this as an answer I'm going to accept it. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting an existing PDF "from the wild" into a compliant [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) is a very complex topic, unless you created it yourself. I rather suggest you use a product from [Callas](https://www.callassoftware.com/en/products/pdfapilot) or [PDF-Tools](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf20/en/products/pdf-converter-validation/#tab-list-9) or another company.

(PDFBox has a command line tool (preflight) to check whether your PDF is PDF/A-1b compliant or not. This can give you a taste of all the shortcomings in "ordinary" PDFs)